# Pass through switch depending on time extension of a certain event

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

I am currently working on a control method which is coupled with a time-frequency analysis of an acceleration frequency: roughly speaking, the control loop is activated only if the frequency content of the acceleration is within a certain bandwidth near the natural frequency of the system I mean to control.

The Simulink loop is represented in the following figure:

[image]

At the moment, after checking that I'm actually within the frequency interval of interest, the signal is going through a switcher. After the switcher the acceleration is moduled via a certain control loop.
The problem is that, at the moment, the control loop is activated and de-activated instantaneously: so, if at `t0` the frequency is within the interval, the control loop is active; however, if at `t1` the frequency is outside the devised range, no control is applied.

What I'd like to do now is the following:

1. Define a minimal time length inside which the frequency content falls into the interval, e.g. the frequency content is within the range [0.25 - 0.3]Hz for 3s (or 6s, 9s, etc.).
2. Put this block within the frequency interval detector and the switch.

In this way, the acceleration will undergo the control action only if the frequency contant stays inside the interval for, at least, a certain period of time (as said before, only if the frequency content is inside the range for at least 3s).

Look forward to suggestions.

Comment: After reading your question twice, my first idea was using a hysteresis. In most cases, this works better for control design than a hard "minimal control time". What do you think?

Comment: At the moment I worked it out by passing the output provided by the interval check through an integrator.
How would your hysteresis technique looked like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Histeresis idea works that way:
You define two intervals. One of them with a  small frequency range and with a large frequency range.
I would try this logic.

[image: Simulink-Screenshot]

Comment: Would you mind to describe a little the advantages of this method compared to time extension, as I meant to proceed with? I'd also appreciate if I may be redirected to a reference about this technique. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aimed to reduce the recurring switch on/off events to get a more stable control design. If you only use that time related logic, you do not take the real "need to control" into account. With the logic I mentioned you decide like that: If my controller is switched off, I only start it if the hard criterion is true. But if the controller is already switched on, I only switch it off if the work is really done. By changing the distance between both (frequency) thresholds you change the duration of your "on-time".

Comment: yep, got it already yesterday: to be sure, I will run a set of simulation with both methods in order to ascertain advs and disadvs of each of them.